# Daf Yomi Scheduling for Shabbos, Yom Tov, and Sundays

Tags: torah-study, time, daf-yomi

With the twelfth Siyum HaShas behind us, I was wondering what is the best way for a person to maintain their Daf Yomi schedule on Shabbos, Yom Tov, and Sundays. Is it best to learn at a different time on these days, or perhaps do a double Shiur on Sundays? I am looking for ideas that have worked for others.

Comment: Is there something about the mentioned days that makes it difficult to maintain the _daf yomi_ schedule on them?

Comment: If you are learning 6AM or 10PM on a weekday then those times will usually not work on a Shabbos, Yom Tov, or Sunday.

Comment: @GershonGold, if you learn on your lunch break at the office, I can see why that might pose a challenge, but why should 6am or 10pm be a problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that the question is dealing with a USA schedule (unless you want to broaden it).

Comment: If one listens to a recorded shiur, for example...

Answer (score 4):

My local (USA) Young Israel synagogue has *daf yomi* classes Sunday mornings after *shacharis*, Monday through Thursday evenings, and *Shabas* afternoons before *mincha*. (That's six days of the week; I guess they cram seven days' worth into six days as best they can.)

In an Agudath Israel synagogue I used to pray in (in the USA also), *daf yomi* was before *shacharis* every day of the week, and, since they tended to cover less than a *daf* a day, also sometimes after *shacharis* on Sundays.

Comment: This seems to answer the question as asked. I'm not sure whether the question as asked is what the asker intended....

Answer (score 2):

Our Shul has two times: Sunday through Friday mornings at 6:00 and Sunday through Thursday nights at 8:45. The Friday night shiur is given Shabbos morning before Shacharis, and Shabbos afternoon's shiur is both groups combined.
Basically Shabbos day you could have a shiur before or after any davening, or, if you specifically need electronic resources, just do it after Shabbos.

Comment: binyamingavriel, thanks for the data point and advice, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1781/binyamingavriel), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.