# Daf yomi on Tisha b'Av

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tisha-bav, daf-yomi

There is a strong tradition (maybe halakha?) to not engage in most learning on Tisha b'Av (with a few exceptions).  Many of us learn daily and I understand that we generally suspend our learning for that one day (or choose to learn a permitted topic, like hilchot Tisha b'Av).

However, daf yomi - a page of Talmud every day - is more organized.  People globally learn on the same schedule.  And [that schedule](http://www.dafyomi.org/machzor.php) seems to include 9 Av.  What gives?  Why are we allowed to learn Pesachim 26 on 9 Av but almost nothing else?

Comment: Relevant to someone who has this question may be [how to schedule the missed _daf_](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18257). And [a similar question's been asked about _Pirke Avos_](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17967).

Comment: [Halakha](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=30&format=pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Although there is a Daf for the day of Tisha B'Av it should not be learned on Tisha B'Av itself. It should be done either prior or after Tisha B'Av instead.](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/188725-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91)

Comment: perfect!  Citation: הרב צבי יניר

Comment: +1. It's curious that he recommends (or rules) to learn part the day before and part the day after, and not to learn all of it whenever one has the chance (the day before and/or the day after).

Answer (score 3):

Just a note from an similar topic:
The Chabad custom is to learn every day a portion of Chumash, Tanya, and Tehillim, collectively known as [Chitas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitas), as well as a portion of Rambam's Mishneh Torah and/or Sefer Hamitzvos. These are daily studies just as Daf Yomi is daily. The Chabad Minhag, as cited in [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30479&st=&pgnum=55) Book of Chabad Minhagim (Hebrew), translated into English [here](http://www.sichos-in-english.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/49.htm), and [this](http://crownheights.info/notices/7513/halachos-and-minhogim-for-tishaa-bav/) English article, regarding Tisha B'av is to not learn Chitas before Chatzos, and it is preferable to do it before Mincha with Tallis and Tefillin, Rambam however is made up Motzei Tish B'av. I am not sure why a differentiation exists, and not sure which category Daf Yomi would fit in.

Comment: We don't say Chitas before Chatzos? Why not? (Is it because the morning is supposed to be devoted to chassidic learning, not kria?) How important/strict is this minhag? Is it mentioned in any Chabad sources?

Comment: I couldn't get to the location in Sefer Haminhagim in English-- link seems to be broken--so I couldn't read it. As for the article, I don't see where it seems to specify that chitas is said after chatzot. I did, on the other hand, find two mentions that chitas "pertains" to shacharis. Could you perhaps quote the relevant part of sefer haminhagim for me?

Comment: I figured this was because we are more lenient with learning in the afternoon of Tisha B'Av--So those who have a daily routine of studying Chitas every day don't have to miss a day, but should study it in the afternoon (on Tisha B'Av only). Is that not what it means? Do you have any other source for the custom to say Chitas preferably after chatzos?

Comment: Yes, I know. But we aren't saying the same thing. I am suggesting that the sefer's recommendation to say Chitas after chatzos was a recommendation for Tisha B'Av only.

Comment: I thought you were suggesting that "Minhag Chabad [in general] is to not learn Chitas before Chatzos" on any day. .... That Chabad only learns Chitas after Chatzos *on Tisha BAv* is not a community-specific minhag, afaict, but an application of the universal laws of Torah learning on Tisha BAv.

Comment: Oh wow totally missed that, fixed my answer to be more readable.

Comment: OK! So as far as you know, then, there's no daily minhag in Chabad to say chitas after chatzos?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: @SAH Chitas is preferably done right after shachrit, but may be done throughout the day.